# How to Resolve these Alsa warnings by /etc/asound.conf?

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, zenbook

Examples of Alsa warnings got by many applications (etc Matlab 2016a), which naturally appear in many applications but which differentiation into important and non-important ones has been difficult for me; I keep all warnings important, once I get them so I really would like to silent non-important warnings

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:947:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:947:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
```

MathWorks' support service proposes to silent the warnings by Alsa config file `/etc/asound.conf`. However, I disagree with their policies of giving such warnings in the first place i.e. calling the function `audiodevinfo` each time when calling `sound/soundsc/audioplayer/audiorecorder` commands in Matlab 2016a. So I would like to understand how it is good to silent those warnings such that you do not miss any critical piece of information. Open

- ignorance - application specific
- ...

Characteristics of the system

- `root@masi:/home/masi# less /proc/asound/cards`

  ```
  0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf128000 irq 127
  ```

### Rejected proposals

1. Edit `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` and change

   ```
   # https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=129648
   pcm.front cards.pcm.default # original pcm.front cards.pcm.front but issue with Matlab
   ```
2. Restart pulse

   ```
   pulseaudio -k
   ```
3. Output: unsuccessful, the errors keep coming

### Matlab 2016a's part

Answer from MathWork's tech support

> These warnings are generated when you execute the "audiodevinfo" function for the first time which is called internally when you execute the "sound/soundsc/audioplayer/audiorecorder" commands. The "audiodevinfo" tries to enumerate all the devices on the system.
>
> The warnings are generated by the ALSA system libraries and it does not affect the behavior of MATLAB. The cause of this issue is not related to MATLAB. I would like to suggest you to take a look at the ALSA config files such as "/etc/asound.conf" to resolve the warning messages. However, assisting you with editing the ALSA config files would be outside the scope of our Technical Support.

I think Matlab should design their product such that you do not get those warnings. 
It can a mark of bad design if you call such an info function from another function.

How to proceed with the design of `/etc/asound.conf`?

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 (backports)
Matlab: 2016a, 2016b prerelease
Related: [How to Configure ALSA in Ubuntu 16.04 for Macbook and Matlab?](https://askubuntu.com/q/800134/25388) but for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common solution is to just ignore them at the moment because they should not be complicating and/or harming anything.